Application of Geometry of Banach spaces in modern days or in other studies
I plan to pursue my higher studies in the geometry of Banach spaces. I am curious about the recent era of artificial intelligence, machine learning etc. Is there any field where Banach space geometry is being used nowadays? I do not have any knowledge about the application of any part of Banach space geometry so far. Can anyone please suggest to me some areas, or disciplines related to its application? Any reference is appreciated. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

You could look at the paper "ON THE BANACH SPACES ASSOCIATED WITH MULTI-LAYER RELU NETWORKS" on arxiv that deals with Banach spaces and Neural networks, and the references therein. You could also have a look at this article.

Definitely I will see. Thank you for the reference.
